# How can I detect bad characters and differences in two dataframes with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I need to check the differences between the test dataframe(df_test) and the reference dataframe (df_reference). I need to report the presence of characters like single quotes or double quotes, space or uppercase that should not be present in the test dataframe:

```
list_reference = ['hey', 'ola', 'bonjour', 'Hello']
list_test = ['Hey', 'ol a', 'bon'jour', 'He"llo']

df_reference = pd.DataFrame(list_reference)
df_test = pd.DataFrame(list_test)
```

I would like to find the simplest solution with pandas to detect the words which are not identical with the df_reference and to put an error message to indicate that there is presence of a quote, double quote, capital letter or space on a word from df_test.

what is the best solution? Pandas, python difflib? The solution that uses the least code?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Do you want to compare each test word with every single reference word, or can you compare 'hey' to 'Hey', 'ola to 'ol a', and so on... without having to go through all of the other words?

Comment: hello @DerekO, i would like to  compare 'hey' to 'Hey', 'ola to 'ol a', and so on... without having to go through all of the other words. I want to warn by information message the presence of the bad character present in the dataframe reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need to compare the test and reference words in pairs, I would put both lists in the same DataFrame so each pair of words is in the same row. Then for your function, you can iterate through each letter of the test word and check if it is contained in the corresponding reference word. This is sort of hacky, but in your case should work since you are checking for mostly special characters.

It's worth noting that this solution doesn't work for repeated, multiple capital letters (for example, if you have the reference word "Hi" and the test word "HiH"). I would be happy to suggest a workaround for this, if you can provide more information about the nature of your test words. Could the above situation occur?

```
list_reference = ['hey', 'ola', 'bonjour', 'Hello']
list_test = ['Hey', 'ol a', 'bon\'jour', 'He"llo']
df = pd.DataFrame({'reference':list_reference, 'test':list_test})
```

Then create a new column called "error", and apply the function rowwise using the pandas `apply` function and the argument `axis=1`:

```
df['error'] = df.apply(lambda x: [char for char in x['test'] if char not in x['reference']], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
  reference      test error
0       hey       Hey   [H]
1       ola      ol a   [ ]
2   bonjour  bon'jour   [']
3     Hello    He"llo   ["]
```